# Add a column while using mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am using `mysqlimport` to import 5 different `csv` files into a common database table using a bash script.

```
File[0]=one
File[1]=two
File[2]=three
File[3]=four
File[4]=five

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
do 
   mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="<br />\n" -uusername -ppassword --local tablename /path/${File[i]}.txt
done
```

Now I wanted add an extra column to the common table, which has a unique id for each file. Eg. For all entries of one.csv, the id would have value 1. 
Is there a way I can do this at the same time as import through the bash script? I do not want to go the mysql console each time and do it from there.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) is just a wrapper for the [`LOAD DATA INFILE` SQL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html), and while mysqlimport is a nice convenience, it has a couple limitations that are going to make what you're trying to do difficult, namely:

1. You can't specify table names, it infers the table name from the file name
2. The very option that you're hoping to use, where you can `set` a field to a given value on import, doesn't exist as an option for mysqlimport (although it does exist on the bare SQL!)

Because of this, you likely want to skip the mysqlimport and execute the sql statement directly.

Something like this should do:

```
File[0]=one
File[1]=two
File[2]=three
File[3]=four
File[4]=five

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
do
  qry="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/${File[i]}.txt' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"<br />\n\"  (list,comma,separated,column,names,here) SET source_id='$i'"

  mysql -uusername -ppassword << eof
  $qry
  eof
done
```

The `SET source_id='$i'` field is the key to setting that field on import.

Note: this code is untested but it should get you going in the right direction, just read the mysql manual for `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and google "mysql bash".

Comment: Thanks. The LOAD DATA is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

how about an approach like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo>/tmp/tmpfile.csv

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
  for j in `cat ${FILE[i]}.TXT`; do echo $i,$j>>/tmp/tmpfile.csv; done
done

mysqlimport ..... --table localfile /tmp/tmpfile.csv
rm -f /tmp/tmpfile.csv
```

of course this is incomplete/untested code, but you get the idea of first creating a complete file with added column, and then importing that one.

you also could bypass mysqlimport and construct the sql similarly:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo>/tmp/tmpfile.csv

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
  for j in `cat ${FILE[i]}.TXT`; do echo "insert into tablename (a,b,c,d,e) values ($i,$j);">>/tmp/tmpfile.csv; done
done

mysql -D dbname -u user --password=pass < /tmp/tmpfile.csv
rm -f /tmp/tmpfile.csv
```

Comment: in case you missed it: \`cat file.txt\` will give you each line of each file, so you can easily add something in front of each line. or at end if you like.